# windows7 unable to reinstall the uninstalled program

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

I installed QNX Momentics IDE and uninstalled.Now i am trying to install the same version I am getting the error,The installation cannot continue because this product is already installed. If you
wish to reinstall it, please uninstall it first.
Please help us how to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I have same problem. how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check registry records "regedit" and delete the records related to the software, also install ccleaner to delete the unnecessary file might remain after uninstalling the software.